# Unable to match express route path with query params

Tags: node.js, express

I am calling the path as:

```
Axios.get('/api/getUsersData/?location='+location+'&managerId='+managerId)
```

and the `routes` is configured as:

```
router.get('/api/getUsersData/?location=:location&managerId=:managerId', handler.getUsersDataByLocationAndManager)
```

But the handler isn't getting called! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route isn't set up correctly. You're mixing query parameters with route parameters.

Change your configured route to:

```
router.get('/api/getUsersData', handler.getUsersDataByLocationAndManager)
```

and access the query parameters with:

`req.query.location` and `req.query.managerId`

You can find more information about this here:

- (Query Params) http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.query
- (Route Params) http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.params

Comment: My bad, I edited the path. Your suggestion worked. You have any idea about handling undefined or null values for those params? I am right now substituting them with empty string.

Comment: It depends how you want to handle them. If they are required for the endpoint, then you should consider making them route parameters where possible (Which will force any calls to be validated by express first, before any manual validation of their input - this usually guarantees _some_ value for the parameters.

If they're not always required, and are optional/additional endpoint variables, then you enforce some validation on the front-end, and some default values (if applicable) on the back end.